# Spark cannot serialize object inside a function?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using Spark 1.5.

I run the following code and get exception `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`

```
def work() = {
  val rdd1:RDD[String] = read_rdd()
  val map:Map[String,Boolean] = read_a_map()

  object brx extends Serializable { val value = map }

  def filter(rdd:RDD[String]) = {
    rdd filter brx.value.apply //throws exception
  }

  def filter2(rdd:RDD[String]) = {
    rdd filter map //works fine
  }

  val x = filter(rdd1)  //throws exception
  val x = filter2(rdd1) // works fine
}
```

Why I got `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`?

Comment: You should post full stack trace

Comment: You should correct the name of post from serilaize to serialize.